# python3 で _tkinter を import したい

Tags: python, tkinter

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

を試してみたのですが

```
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

とでてしまいます

様々な検索をしましたが同じエラーが起きているサイトを見つけても

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

を行えば改善されたと記載されています。
`python3-tk`も試してみたのですが_tkinterのmoduleがないといわれます
どなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Pythonのversionは3.5.2です

Comment: `python3-tk` とか?

Comment: そちらも試してみたのですが_tkinterのmoduleがないといわれます。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_tkinter`を提供しているパッケージは`python3-tk`で間違いないです。

```
>>> import _tkinter
>>> _tkinter.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
```

```sh
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
python3-tk: /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

システム標準の Python でなく自分でインストールした Python を使用している可能性があります。

```
>>> import sys
>>> print("sys.executable: ", sys.executable)
sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python3
```

のようにして確認してみて下さい。
(上記は Ubuntu 16.10 で確認しました）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

上記のディレクトリの中にパッケージを確認しました。

Comment: @塩士亮平 問題は解決された、という事で大丈夫ですか？

Comment: いえ、確認できたからこそなぜ'No module'といわれるのかわかりません。。。
'sys.executable'の出力結果は'home/dl_user/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/pyrhon'とでました。

Comment: @塩士亮平  システム標準の（`apt` で管理されている）Python3 は `/usr/bin/python3` です。`sys.executable` の出力を見るに、やはりご自分でシステムの物とは別にインストールした物を利用されているようですね。それが `apt` でインストールしたモジュールを利用できない理由です。`/usr/bin/python3` を実行すれば大丈夫です。

Comment: /user/bin/python3
の実行とはどういう意味ですか？

Comment: @塩士亮平  おそらくは、ただ`python`と実行すると、ご自分でインストールした Python が実行されるよう、`$PATH`などを設定なさっているのではないでしょうか。この設定を止めるか、フルパスで`/usr/bin/python3`とコマンドを入力して実行する、という事です。

Comment: コマンドラインに直接パスを指定して実行すればtkinterno

Comment: tkinterのモジュールエラーは回避できました！
ご教授ありがとうございました！